# Determinant of prime cyclotomic field.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, proof-explanation, cyclotomic-fields, discriminant

[In this paper](http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2013/REUPapers/Sauder.pdf), Example 5.3, I would like to know how he simplified the Vandermonde determinant. What I am asking is how did he get the steps. I feel like there are some steps missing. Considering there are 7 steps in the solution (7 '='):

**Q1.** Firstly how did he split the product in to two products, what is the theory? (Step 2)

**Q2.**  How did one of the products disappear? What did he apply? (Step 3)

**Q3.** In Step 5, how does the Step 4 term (**with products in the numerator and denominator**) evaluate to $-1/p$

**Q4.** Also the reasoning since $p-1$ is odd doesn't add up as $p-2$ term should remain and not $p-1$ as that is even?

Please kindly explain this proof. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of typos in the source, but here goes.

(1) In more detail:

$$\begin{array}{ll}
\displaystyle \prod_{i<j}(a_i-a_j)^2 & \displaystyle =\prod_{i<j}(a_i-a_j)(a_i-a_j) \\ & =\displaystyle \prod_{i<j}(-1)(a_j-a_i)(a_i-a_j) \\ & =(-1)^N\displaystyle\prod_{i<j}(a_j-a_i)(a_i-a_j) \\ & = \displaystyle(-1)^N\left[\prod_{i<j} (a_j-a_i)\right] \left[\prod_{i<j}(a_i-a_j)\right] \\ & = \displaystyle(-1)^N \left[\prod_{j<i} (a_i-a_j)\right] \left[\prod_{i<j}(a_i-a_j)\right] \\ & = \displaystyle (-1)^N \prod_{i\ne j}(a_i-a_j) \\ & = \displaystyle (-1)^N \prod_i\left[\prod_{\substack{i\ne j \\ i\textrm{ fixed}}} (a_i-a_j)\right]
\end{array} $$

This is not two products, it's a product *of* products. Letting $(i,j)$ range over all possible values with $i\ne j$ is the same as letting $i$ range over all values, and within each possible value of $i$, letting $j$ range over every value except for $i$.

(Above $N$ stands for the number of pairs $(i,j)$ with $i<j$, which is $p-1$ choose $2$.)

(2) We know $X^p-1=(X-1)\prod_j(X-\zeta_j)$. Taking the derivative with the product rule and evaluating at $X=\zeta_i$ yields the formula $-p\zeta_i^{p-1}/(1-\zeta_i)=\prod_{j\ne i}(\zeta_i-\zeta_j)$ (with $i$ fixed).

(3) I assume you know where $(-p)^{p-1}$ comes from. In the numerator,

$$\prod_i \zeta_i^{p-1}=\left(\prod_i \zeta_i\right)^{p-1}=(\zeta^{1+\cdots+(p-1)})^{p-1}=(\zeta^p)^{(p-1)^2/2}=1.$$

In the denominator,

$$\prod_i (1-\zeta_i)=\left.\frac{1-X^p}{1-X}\right|_{X=1}=1^{p-1}+\cdots+1^0=p. $$

(4) In the exponent of $(-1)$, arithmetic is mod $2$. If $p$ is odd, then $p-2\equiv 1$ mod $2$, and you need to keep $p-1$ in order for $(p-1)/2$ to make sense mod $2$.

Comment: What do you mean by p-1 choose 2? Also in 4) how do you say that the arithmetic is mod 2?

Comment: @Mojo-Jojo (a) The [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) $\binom{p-1}{2}$, aka the combination ${}_{p-1}C_2$. (b) Well, $(-1)^k$ only depends on $k$ mod $2$, so...

Comment: Oh OK. I don't have the basic prerequisites for this course so the silly questions :( Thanks

Comment: How did you get the idea for step 2 in your solution? I am curious as to how to think mathematically?

Comment: @Mojo-Jojo The idea is that for fixed $i$, the product $\prod_{j\ne i}(\zeta_i-\zeta_j)$ is most of the factorization of $X^p-1$ at $X=\zeta_i$. Then the question becomes how to bridge the gap between the given product and the actual factorization. (Differentiating and evaluating at a root is in fact a standard technique.)